# JSF 2.0 EL tags don't render in browser

Tags: html, eclipse, jsf-2, tomcat7, el

The following is my `index.html` file which contains the JSF: http://pastie.org/3755252

When I choose `Run as > Run on Server` (Tomcat 7.0.12) in Eclipse Indigo I get a page which says only the following:

```
You have login attempts left.
```

The same happens in Chrome. Although after looking at the source of the page, it displayed just as I have it written in Eclipse (the previous pastie file), but it seems like it should be translated to html.

This is my Member.java file: http://pastie.org/3755277
And here is my web.xml: http://pastie.org/3755284

It used to work, before I noticed I was mixing JSF 2.0 with JSF1.* syntax. Then I changed my *.jsp to *.html and it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated web.xml, with two versions and what each does: http://pastie.org/3759169

Comment: The statement *"it displayed just as I have it written in Eclipse"* conflicts with the title. Please clarify the concrete problem. What do you see when you do rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser? Do you really understand what it means when you say "EL" as in title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pastie seems to be down (I can't read your files)... but Tomcat isn't a full Java EE container. You'd need the Mojarra runtime. Do you have that included in your build?

EDIT: NM it's back. I see the JSF servlet in your web.xml, so you may disregard this answer.

EDIT2: Add this to your web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Then rename your .html files to .xhtml. I have a feeling the servlet didn't know it was supposed to render your files using JSF.

EDIT3: So I think what's happening is your confusing the server on whether or not it should render the page using Faces. You're URL in your url bar is "localhost/app/faces/index.html" which matches a file exactly. So should it do a sendfile or should it run it through the servlet? The reason why renaming to .xhtml likely worked was because internally it knew it had to map a .html request to a .xhtml file.

So maybe try renaming your files to .html5, then set this in your web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.html5</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

I think any extension will work... You could also do this combination:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.html</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Then your home page would be `http://localhost/app/index.jsf`

Comment: I'm trying to use HTML5, would *.xhtml still be valid for HTML5? I've tried servlet mapping of the following `...<url-pattern>*.html<url-pattern>..` but the server keeps crashing when I tried loading the page.

Comment: First, notice that my XML isn't a servlet mapping, it's a context param. Next, you can change it to `.html` and it should still work. Do not change your servlet mapping, you already have it set correctly.

Comment: Ah, I tried to map the servlet and the context param at the same time before, but I didn't understand the idea behind the servlet mapping and I couldn't find any information on the `context-param` configuration. Thanks, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Tried it with `.html` but it did not work, but then I tried it with `.xhtml` and renamed my files to `*.xhtml` and that worked... So what's the problem with it reading .html?

Comment: So the servelet mapping maps external to the servlet. Then the context parm maps a servlet to the files. I imagine having them set to the same thing caused a problem... I'm not really sure to be honest.

Comment: Not really, since I still can't render .html, but only .xhtml which doesn't run with html5 syntax.

Comment: Ah ok! Post your new Web.xml and let's take a look

Comment: Check my comment in my original post.

Comment: What URL are you going to when you want to invoke your webpage? Is it `http://localhost/myapp/faces/index.html`

Comment: After adding `context:.html5` and `servlet-mapping:*.jsf` The page loaded but exactly like I have in my original post (although it had a .jsf extension)

Comment: I also tried renaming the files to `.html5` and changing the `context` to `*.html5` but it loaded the same with the page having a .html extension.

*My previous comment should have been `context:.html`

Comment: To be clear, your context param can NOT match the servlet mapping

Comment: Yeah I got that :) So context-param specifies which files to render through JSF? and servlet-mapping says what to display in the browser when the file is loaded?

Comment: Yep, the context param says to faces: "Hey here are your templates." The servlet mapping tells the container when to use faces and when to not.