# EL tags not rendered

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf-2, el, tomcat7

My problem is that when I run a very simple JSF application the EL tags are not getting rendered.

For example, this code:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelets Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body> #{hello.world} </h:body>
</html>
```

Is displayed as `#{hello.word}` within the browser, rather than "Hello World!" as should be returned by my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "hello")
public class Hello {
    public String getWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I have seen this question [JSF 2.0 EL tags don't render in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073212/jsf-2-0-el-tags-dont-render-in-browser) already, but it didn't help me. And, according to what I've read, Tomcat 7 claims to provide both API and implementation of the EL 2.2 standard.

I'm using the following software/versions:

- Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 Java EE edition
- Eclipse plugin: m2e 1.0.2
- Eclipse plugin: m2e-wtp 0.15.2
- Maven 2
- Tomcat 7 (have tried the following versions)

  - Tomcat 7.0.10
  - Tomcat 7.0.26
  - Tomcat 7.0.27
- MyFaces 2.1.6
- Oracle JDK 1.7.0

If more information is required I'll gladly provide it.

**[EDIT1]**

I'm not even sure if this is necessary/correct, but adding the following to `web.xml` didn't solve the problem:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**[EDIT2]**

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>jsf-facelets</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>20</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_CLIENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SECRET</param-name>
        <param-value>NzY1NDMyMTA=</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: i guess you try to access your pages as mypage.html ? right? try to check if it works for you with mypage.jsf , and change <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> into  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> also if its jsf2 project you can remove <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: I just tried accessing it as mypage.html instead of mypage.xhtml and it worked

Comment: the strange thing is, I was sure I'd tried this before many times, but... who knows. now it works... thanks for the tip to try changing the extension

Comment: should I just delete this question?

Comment: so you didn't tried accessing the page with .html extension... I will post my comment as an answer (with slight modification) , cause it might be usefull to others... I already seen this type of issues regarding the Faces Servlet mapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access your pages with `.html` extension like that: `myPage.html`

cause of your servlet-mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: how would I set the URL pattern to something like "/faces/*.html" (<-- this doesn't work)? i.e. everything prefixed with the "/faces/" path, that has a .html extension

Comment: are you aware that faces is not a physical folder ? you don't need to place you files inside the faces folder, right? if you set <url-pattern>/faces/*.html</url-pattern> you can't open the page like this /faces/mypage.html ?

Comment: i realize it's not a folder, but i want to map one path (e.g. /faces/*.html) to JSF, and another path (e.g. /rest/*) to all REST calls. how can i tell JSF to (1) only look at .html files [AND] (2) only look at URLs that are prefixed with /faces/?

Comment: if /faces/*.html does not work ,it might be cause it not possible to you prefix and suffix mapping at the same time, sounds like a new question...